# socket.io connection via client not working

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have just started using node.js socket.io. I am working on a simple connection between client and server.

Here is my server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', routes.index);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
var io = socketio.listen(server);
```

and this is the client code(http://smartican.com/nodetest.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket;
socket = io.connect("http://smartican.com:1337/");
$(function() {
 alert(socket.transport.sessionid);  
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

there seems to be a problem when connecting to the socket from client as line

```
socket = io.connect("http://smartican.com:1337/");
```

breaks the script.. I have tested and the socket is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your `socket.io.js`](https://smartican.com/socket.io.js) is the wrong javascript file. It's the server javascript not the client javascript. You want `socket.io-client.js`. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202053/socket-io-require-is-not-defined#answer-8206541).