# how to fix 'require is not defined' error in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, socket.io

In an `express.Js` project i have `socket.io` installed for my server and `socket.io-client` for my client and the projected is bundled using webpack5.

in my client i have this code;

```
const { io } = require("socket.io-client");

const socket = io();

socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log(socket.id);
});
```

and when i run the command to build it compiles without problems but in the browser i get the error ;

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

how can i fix this ?

i couldn't find a good answer here ; [Socket.IO - require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202053/socket-io-require-is-not-defined)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Webpack doesn't seem to be packing it. You'll need to make sure you are using the generated file from webpack and provide your webpack config to debug this.

Comment: `import { io } from "socket.io-client"`

Comment: @VasylBoroviak also this option gives the same error i already fixed the problem of require not defined but with socket it appears again